# how to set `__package__` attribute for relative imports

Tags: python, import, package

```
├── Codes 
│   ├── GeneralizedInversion.py
│   ├── GeometricalSpreading.py
│   ├── HtoV.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── interface
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── pyqtinter.py
│   ├── rocksiteamplification.py
│   └── TheSoftware.py
```

within **pyqtinter.py** i try to import **TheSoftware.py** using

```
from .. import TheSoftware
```

but the error is: **ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package**

This link clears why this error is raising:
[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132870)

in order to solve this issue two main solutions are using sys.path.append(path) or using -m when executing python code so `__name__`  isnt set to `__main__`. it is said that optional attribute `__package__` also can be used for solving this issue but i havent found the way to do it. The question is if i set `__package__` to  *Codes.interface* then is it possible for python to understand relative imports?